# Mysql Date manipulation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with different dates and one of them is separated in 3 fields:
PassDay, PassMonth, PassYear.

I want to compare these dates with an other datetime `orig_date` so what I did is

```
select `orig_date`, CONCAT_WS('-',`PassYear`,`PassMonth`,`PassDay`) as `pass_expiration` where `pass_expiration` < `orig_date`;
```

The problem is that the month is stored as a month name (January) and not a number (01), so my result for `pass_expiration` is 2013-April-15 for example.

Is there a way to transform this (2013-April-15) to a regular datetime directly from the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [`str_to_date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
where STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',PassYear,PassMonth,PassDay),'%Y-%M-%d') < orig_date
```

Also, as a note, you can't reference a computed column in the `where` clause. Only in the `order by` clause (`where` is a predicate that's used to filter results from the table; `order by` is run after the column set is calc'd).

Comment: Possibly a space should be inserted between `PassMonth` and `PassDay`. Also, `+` is not supported as concatenation operator in MySQL, from what I hear. (I am not a regular MySQL user so I'm not sure.)

Comment: I get empty results with that and when i try `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(PassMonth + ' ' + PassDay + ', ' + PassYear,'%M %d,%Y') from data where 1 limit 5` to check, each result is set to `NULL`

Comment: It worked with `where STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',PassYear,PassMonth,PassDay),'%Y-%M-%d') < origdate`

Thanks Eric for `str_to_date`

Comment: Edited for posterity--sorry, I forgot about MySQL not liking + as a concat operator